# Why can't I Execute SQL when I generate database from entity framework model?

Tags: sql, sql-server, entity-framework, visual-studio

I am trying to generate a database from my entity framework model.

That is, I built the  model first in visual studio, and then right click on the model and choose **Generate Database from Model**. I get my **.edmx.sql** file.

When I stand on the code in the .sql file, I'm supposed to be able to right click and select **Execute SQL**.

But this option is NOT showing up!!! When I right click the only options are:

- breakpoint
- run to cursor
- run flag threads to cursor (grayed out)
- cut
- copy
- paste (grayed out)
- outlining

In the past I successfully made a database from this model. Now  I need to update the model and am trying to remake the database. Why is the option not showing up suddenly?

Comment: Before executin, you need to connect to the server. Have you?

Comment: yes I have. Do you have other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You have to follow these steps.

**Step 1 :**

`Right-click` on the design surface and select `Generate Database from Model`

**Step 2 :**

Click `New Connection` and specify either `LocalDb ((localdb)\v11.0)` or `SQL Express (.\SQLEXPRESS)`.

**Step 3 :** Enter `YourDbName` as the database name.

[image]

**Step 4 :**

Select `OK`

**Step 5 :**

Then you will be asked if you want to `create a new database`, select `Yes`

Answer (score 0):

My newer version of Visual Studio did not seem to give me the option to "Execute SQL", so I just did Ctrl-A, Ctrl-C to copy the generated SQL code and then went into my SQL Server Management Studio and pasted it into a new query and hit "Run". That created the new database.